# AWS Lambda .NET Core 2.1 AmazonEC2Client.DescribeInstancesAsync throws TaskCanceledException

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, .net-core, aws-lambda

The Lambda has all the proper rights, it's using a profile I used on my local machine which just works for the job.

I'm using the current latest versions of EC2 Package:

- AWSSDK.EC2 (3.3.57.2)

For some reason, `AmazonEC2Client.DescribeInstancesAsync` throws a `TaskCanceledException` after a 100secs running in the Lambda.

Code looks like this:

```
var resp = Ec2Client.DescribeInstancesAsync(new DescribeInstancesRequest
{
    Filters = new List<Filter>
    {
        new Filter("iam-instance-profile.arn", new List<string> {"myCorrectRole"})
    }
}).Result;
```

The `TaskCanceledException` in question is found within the thrown `AggregateException` and contains a `Message = "A task was canceled"`

Comment: The async task takes too long and that's why you get this exception. Happened to me when I was async calling other Lambda function that takes data from DB, same exception after 100s execution. Not sure if there's a way to make waiting time longer

Comment: @caldazar odd as this only takes like a second on my local machine, there's barely 30 EC2 Instances

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. Do you maybe have some security group settings that would prevent Lambda from accessing EC2 instances?

Comment: Are you publishing the Lambda into a VPC and if so check the permissions/routes for the subnets to make sure it can reach the EC2 endpoint.

Comment: @NormJohanson turns out it was a VPC issue. Thanks to both of you for your help.

Comment: @M.Christopher How did you resolve the issue?

Comment: @JamesB VPC issue, as I mentioned. Don't have the exact details as I don't manage AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue.

It turned out to be due to the Lambda running in a VPC.

When running in a VPC the lambda cannot talk to the public endpoint that the SDK uses to interact with the EC2 platform.

In my case, the Lambda was within a private subnet, I wanted it to remain there so I created a public subnet within the VPC, and a NAT gateway between the two subnets, with the public subnet routing out through an Internet Gateway.

Its also possible to solve it with a VPC endpoint but only if you want to manage AWS resources within the same region as the VPC.